# Can't boot after Ubuntu 15.10 Beta 2 Install

Tags: ubuntu, kernel-panic

After some software problems with Ubuntu 15.04, I installed Ubuntu 15.10 beta 2, I figured that couldn't be much worse, ant now I can't boot off of my hard drive, and even when I try to boot my Ubuntu USB drive I get a kernel panic.

This is new, 2015 hardware, I'm pretty sure there are zero hardware problems.

Manually typing the end of the kernel panic message that I see on the screen when I try to boot off of USB:

```
end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unkown-block(0,0)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. But I had Ubuntu 15.04, windows and Ubuntu 15.10 on different partitions.
I logged into 15.04 and run " sudo update-grub " in terminal. Updated the system. Rebooted and logged into 15.10 after updating.
It worked.
I cleaned 15.04 kernels and it was not listing the latest kernel.
I did the same by logging into 15.10 and updated grub menu. it found the kernel installed.
You can try live usb and then run boot repair from it. if boot repair is not there install it on usb.
It may fix your problem
Make usb from windows if it is not booting. i made it from Ubuntu and it did not boot.